# how to programmatically generate an 11 character app unique key for release?

Tags: android, android-keystore

I am using [google message retriever api](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/verify) for reading sms OTP without asking for permission, I generated 11 character unique key for app by using [this](https://gist.github.com/rodrigohsb/a7dd038a43502328d94a85c4494072e2). This link generates the key that is working well for app in debug mode, but this key is not working in release mode. I am searching for **Java code** to generate key for production not **command**. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: well, you need a separate key for release (run the code in a release build to find it)

Comment: @TimCastelijns, Yes, for generating release key, I am looking for Java Code

Comment: @Zoe, thanks Zoe, for correction.

Comment: it's the same code man. Just run it in release instead of debug

Comment: @TimCastelijns, I am checking

Comment: Go to android studio, click on build variants tab on the left sidemenu, select release, and run the app

Answer (score 0):

You can generate through command line:

keytool -exportcert -alias YOUR_KEYSTORE_ALIAS -keystore YOUR_KEYSTORE_FILE | xxd -p | tr -d "[:space:]" | echo -n YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME `cat` | sha256sum | tr -d "[:space:]-" | xxd -r -p | base64 | cut -c1-11

Comment: Thanks for your anwser, But in the question I mentioned, I am looking for java code.